# jQueryMobile MVC3 not redirecting to home page on Login - even though Visual Studio Debugging window shows the page is loading through code

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I am having an odd issue with MVC3 on my site.  I have a simple login form using MVC3 and jQueryMobile.  The login functionality is working properly.  Once I press login the loading graphic shows and I can step through the code and see that the home page is loading.  However, the login page still shows on the screen after I trace the code.  Can you all offer any suggestions?  I am using RC1 of jQueryMobile at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Chrome or IE9 F12 developer tools to debug. Go through my [ASP.NET MVC 4 Mobile Feature](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features)s tutorial.  You should also use Fiddler tool to see what's going on.